# JQuery Fade out & content replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a recommend box for my tumblr. I have a slight issue though. On my blog I have a recommend box that floats on the left of the blog div, `#cage`. When you click yes, it redirects to a recommend link. When you hit no, I JUST want the div to fade out. For me, once I click no, it fades out fine, but then the `#cage` div moves over to the left and replaces the space that `#recommend` was in. Is there any way to just simply fade out the div, then once it's faded out, replace it with an INVISIBLE div, (the same size as `#recommed`) to it just fades out & the content doesn't move? Thanks. Here's what I have so far, hopefully someone can help.

```
    <div id="recommend">
<img id="Recommend" src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2z7nz9e.png" usemap="#Recommend" border="0" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
<map id="Recommend" name="Recommend">
<area shape="rect" coords="78,113,142,163" href="http://www.tumblr.com/directory/recommend/entertainment/epicjamess" alt="Yes" title="Yes"    />
<div id="no"><area shape="rect" coords="144,113,195,163" href="#" alt="No" title="No" /></div>
</map>
</div>
<script>
  $("#no").click(function () {
  $("#reccommend").fadeOut("fast");
  });
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fading, change the opacity:

```
$("#reccommend").animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
```

The second argument is the duration of the animation in milliseconds.

Comment: Could you say *how* it doesn't work? There are a *lot* of ways to break something ;)

Comment: <script>
  $("#no").click(function () {
$("#reccommend").animate({opacity: '0'}, 200);
  });
}  
</script> Doesn't do anything.

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc2pz/5/. Maybe your code isn't working at all because of an error. Is it running on your site?

Comment: No it's running on tumblr. <script>
  $("#no").click(function () {
  $("#reccommend").animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
  });
  </script> should work, correct? :/

Answer (score 0):

U could try

```
$("#reccommend").animate({opacity: 0}, fast );
```

But keep in mind, opacity is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity also causes issues with text in IE... Maybe try this:

```
<script>
  $("#no").click(function () {
    //wrap it in a div with an id
    $("#reccommend").wrap('<div id="reccomend-wrap" />');

    //set width of the wrapper to match width of #reccomend, and float it
    $("#reccommend-wrap").width($("#reccomend").width()).css("float","left");

    //now fade the #recommend out
    $("#reccommend").fadeOut("fast");
  });
}  
</script>
```

**EDIT:** To prevent jumpiness it might actually be best to have #reccomend-wrap have the same CSS as #reccomend in your CSS file, rather than adding the float property on the fly..